# Чи нормативно вживати "слоїк"?

Tags: вживання-слів

Нещодавно натрапила на цікаве повідомлення у блозі [Андрія Кокотюха](https://zaxid.net/banka_i_sloyik_n1380907) щодо вживання слів **банка** і **слоїк**. Зацікавило це запитання і знайшла неоднозначну інформацію. **Слоїк** знаходжу і в [СУМі](http://sum.in.ua/s/slojik) і в [Словарі українського сленгу](http://slovopedia.org.ua/57/53409/375847.html). **Банка** знаходжу лише в [СУМі](http://sum.in.ua/s/banka) (отже, це не жаргонізм і не діалектизм).

Отже, чи нормативно вживати слово **слоїк**?

Answer (score 2):

Якщо відкрити [Вікіпедію](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0_(%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0)), то одразу бачимо, що банка це те саме, що слоїк ("Ба́нка або сло́їк — скляна посудина з широкою шийкою, яка використовується в основному для зберігання продуктів домашнього і промислового консервування"). Також зустрічаємо слово "слоїк" у [словнику uk.WorldwideDictionary.org](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%97%D0%BA) (який імовірно дублює інформацію із [«Словників України on-line» від УМІФ](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/)). Крім цього, якщо ми подивимося переклад слова "банка" у [Російсько-українському академічному словнику Кримського та Єфремова](http://lang.slovopedia.org.ua/11/53393/119177.html), то бачимо варіанти "банка" та "слоїк".

Слід також враховувати при вживанні цього слова, що "слоїк" — це [полонізм](http://slovopedia.org.ua/57/53409/375847.html) (і походить від польського "słoik"). Однак така ж сама справа із "банкою", адже це [росіянізм](https://uk.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0#%D0%95%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%8F).